# Rails: Association was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a `User` model with a `has_many :through` relationship to the `Publication` model. The `Publication` model in turn has a `has_many :through` relationship to `Author`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :library_publications, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Library::Publication"
  has_many :publications, :through => :library_publications
end

class Library::Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :user
end

class Publication < PublicationBase
  has_many :library_publications, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Library::Publication"
  has_many :users, :through => :library_publications
  has_many :publication_contributions, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Publication::Contribution"
  has_many :authors, :through => :publication_contributions
end

class Author < AuthorBase
  has_many :publication_contributions, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Publication::Contribution"
  has_many :publications, :through => :publication_contributions
end

class Publication::Contribution < Publication::ContributionBase
  belongs_to :publication, :class_name => "Publication"
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "Author"
end
```

As far as I can tell, all the associations are written correctly. However, when I try to eagerload authors from a user:

```
@user.library_publications.includes(:publication => [:authors])
```

I get this error:

```
Association named 'authors' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: I think you have a typo here: `class Publication::Contribution < Publication::ContributionBase`

Comment: Good eye. I should have explained that. `Publication::ContributionBase` is an STI class. There are a couple of other ones in this example, too. Perhaps the STI is interfering with the association in some way, though?

Comment: That's what i tought. But i am not sure yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting a little, I discovered that all of `publication`'s associations were broken. This led to me to looking for larger problems, and eventually I discovered that this issue was caused by one of the join-table being namespaced, `Library::Publication`. When I de-namespaced it, `publication`'s associations began working again.

I'm not sure why this happened, though. If anyone has an explanation, please share.